# evaluating variables in string vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

```
sReport = "EFGHIJKLM"
sSource = "FGHIJKLMN"

For J = 5 To 18
    For I = 1 To Len(sReport)

wbTarget.Sheets(sheetTargetName).Range(Mid(sReport, I, 1) & J) = "=HK_USD!(Mid(sSource, I, 1) & J+79)+London_USD!(Mid(sSource, I, 1) & J+79)+Labuan_USD!(Mid(sSource, I, 1) & J+79)+NY_USD!(Mid(sSource, I, 1) & J+79)+NISP_USD!F84+OWH_USD!(Mid(sSource, I, 1) & J+79)"

     Next
Next
```

I have this formula as shown in the line above. Basically, I want that line to evaluated as

```
wbTarget.Sheets(sheetTargetName).Range("E5") = "=HK_USD!F84+London_USD!F84+Labuan_USD!F84+NY_USD!F84+NISP_USD!F84+OWH_USD!D4"
```

and the Range will change to F5, G5, H5 etc because of the loops. The left side of the formula works. The problem is the one in the string. How can I change this code so that it will evaluate my variables in the string? Thanks

Comment: you can create an array for those strings and call them using the loop variable I.     sReport=array("E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M") then call them as sReport(I)

Comment: re: '*=HK_USD!(Mid(...*' you cannot concatenate a string into a true cell reference without INDIRECT. However, INDIRECT is to be (best practices) avoided. Post the formula you want to appear and a better solution sgould be evident.

Comment: @Desmond, would you mind taking your time and close your previous questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
strFormula="=HK_USD!" & (Mid(sSource, I, 1) & J+79) & "+London_USD!" & (Mid(sSource, I, 1) & J+79) & " +Labuan_USD!" & (Mid(sSource, I, 1) & J+79) & " +NY_USD!" & (Mid(sSource, I, 1) & J+79) & "+NISP_USD!F84+OWH_USD!" & (Mid(sSource, I, 1) & J+79)
wbTarget.Sheets(sheetTargetName).Range(Mid(sReport, I, 1) & J)=strFormula
```